# Negative exponent in division in Sympy

Tags: sympy, division, exponent

I make a division

```
fn=n/3**(n+1)
```

But the view has

```
fn=3**(-n-1)*n
```

Please tell me how to force as fn=n/3**(n+1)

Answer (score 0):

Other than modifying the printer, I can only think of symbol-trickery: make the denominator a Symbol:  `n/Symbol('3^{n+1}')`.